# Error saving tags in Django Taggit

Tags: django, django-taggit

I have my models.py as

```
class TaggedActionsBefore(GenericTaggedItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="%(class)s_emotionsbefore")


class TaggedActionsAfter(GenericTaggedItemBase):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, related_name="%(class)s_emotionsafter")


class ActionJournal(models.Model):

    situation = models.TextField()
    actions_before = TaggableManager(blank=True, through=TaggedActionsBefore, help_text="")
    actions_after = TaggableManager(blank=True,  through=TaggedActionsAfter, related_name="actionsafter", help_text="")
```

I am getting the following error when I am trying to save tags

```
get() returned more than one Tag -- it returned 2!
```

through a form which is model a model form of the ActionJournal model.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> get() returned more than one Tag -- it returned 2!

The above error indicates that you have more than one record in the DB related to the specific parameter you passed while querying using get() such as

> Model.objects.get(field_name=some_param)

To avoid this kind of error in the future, you always need to do query as per your schema design. In your case you designed a table with M2M relationship so obviously there will be multiple records for that field and that is the reason you are getting the above error.

So instead of using get() you should use filter() which will return multiple records. Such as

> Model.objects.filter(field_name=some_param)

Please read about how to make queries in django [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/).

Comment: I wasn't using the get, it is from the django taggit where the error came which was because I changed the case sensitivity by TAGGIT_CASE_INSENSITIVE = True